# Firestore.instance.collection(collectio_name).document(document_name).get(), does not get any value from firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, mobile-development

**So here I am trying to fetch the data from firebase by using DocumentSnapshot.
 I want to print the value of document['display_name']**

- Collection = user_data
- document = 3vIf92LIJQ7pu7MpUwH1
- display_name = element of document.

Output: 'Error has Occured' on screen

```
     class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
         Future<DocumentSnapshot> getDocument() async {
             return Firestore.instance
            .collection('user_data')
            .document('3vIf92LIJQ7pu7MpUwH1')
            .get();
          }

     @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {

           return Container(
           child: Center(
           child: FutureBuilder(
           future: getDocument(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error has occured');
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(snapshot.data['display_name']),
          ],
        );
      }
```

Comment: Have you checked to security rules of firestore?

Comment: yes changing security rules of firestore made it work.

Comment: The things I changed was:Go in Database -> Rules ->
Change allow read, write: if false; to true; (I dont think this is the best solution for this as it removes the entire security of google authentication). Any alternate solution would be helpful. @dshukertjr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an error because of your firestore security rules. Also, you will need to access snapshot.data.data['display_name'] instread of snapshot.data['display_name'] to get the value from firestore.

```
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(snapshot.data.data['display_name']),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: I changed my database security rules and it did worked for me.

Comment: can you find the solution for this issue?link as follows [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142173/not-able-to-access-the-data-from-firebase-using-streambuilder-in-flutter?noredirect=1#comment106385199_60142173)

Comment: @Harsh I will take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

If `hasError` is `true`, you'll want to print `snapshot.error` to see what the actual problem is:

```
if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error has occurred: ${snapshot.error}');
```

Comment: Error performing get, Permission_denied: missing or insuuficient permission was the error, so I just change the security rule and it worked.

Comment: can you find the solution for this issue?link as follows [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142173/not-able-to-access-the-data-from-firebase-using-streambuilder-in-flutter?noredirect=1#comment106385199_60142173)

Comment: I did upvote for your answer at the begining itself because it did helped me but I thinks its the rules of stackoverflow to show that. Following message I recieved after giving an upvote to your answers or anyone else answer : **Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.**