# Not able to access the data from firebase using StreamBuilder in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, mobile-development

Here I am trying to get the **data from the firebase database using firstore instance in streamBuilder**.

- .collection('/message_data/friendA##friendB/message_list') :-this is my collection-document path from firebase

No error, just a blank page.

```
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text(widget.friendName),
     ),
     body: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
          child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('/message_data/friendA##friendB/message_list')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error on chatView ${snapshot.error.toString()}');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (snapshot.data.documents .length > 0) {
                return ListView.builder(

                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot _document = snapshot.data.documents[index];



                    return ChatMessage(
                      isFriend: _document['fromA'],

                      isNotPrevious:snapshot.data.documents.length - 1 == index,
                      message: _document['content'],
                      friendInitial: 'T',

                      avatarUrl:'https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/132/132399.jpg',
                    );
                  },
                );

              }
              else{
                return Text('No messages found in chat view length vala'); 
              }
            }
            else{
                return Text('No messages found in chat view hasdata'); 
              }
          }
          else{
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      )),
```

Comment: try print `_document`.

Comment: @JohnJoe Nothing is getting printed.

Comment: try debug. Did it go to this  `if (snapshot.hasData)`?

Comment: @JohnJoe.Tried doing that as well. No it didn't go to  if (snapshot.hasData).

Comment: then where it went?

Comment: @JohnJoe I see that it isn't even getting into that dart file.

Comment: maybe upload your project to github?

Comment: @JohnJoe Yes I will. I will notify you here once I upload the project.

Comment: also let me access your firebase if possible.

Comment: @JohnJoe [link](https://github.com/riac999/Flutter-Chat-App.git).

Comment: @JohnJoe facing issue in chatView.dart file.

Comment: can I access firebase?

Comment: @JohnJoe Is it possible to look into the issue without a firebase access?

Comment: Will update you after check

Comment: @JohnJoe Any update regarding the issue?

Comment: can you post the whole project instead of file?

Comment: @JohnJoe I dont know but there is a problem somewhere cannot upload the entire project just the files are getting updated. I have updated it somehow, just have a look. I am really stuck at this point and needs a help.

Comment: is it possible to upload the whole project folder?

Comment: Yes! Once I upload it will notify you

Comment: I don't know why it's not giving you an error, but I think it is a problem with the firestore security rule. Could you copy and paste the current security rule in your question?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69901681/unable-to-fetch-data-from-firebase-firestore-using-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69901681/unable-to-fetch-data-from-firebase-firestore-using-flutter) I am facing same issue.Is it working for you now ?????

Comment: [i am facing same issue, here. Did youre problem resolve???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69901681/unable-to-fetch-data-from-firebase-firestore-using-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some error in your snapshot, but you also have an error in how you access your firestore data here. You have to access the data property of your DocumentSnapshot in order to access the data.

```
DocumentSnapshot _document = snapshot.data.documents[index];
Map chatData = _document.data;


return ChatMessage(
    isFriend: chatData['fromA'],

    isNotPrevious:snapshot.data.documents.length - 1 == index,
    message: chatData['content'],
    friendInitial: 'T',

    avatarUrl:'https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/132/132399.jpg',
);
```

Comment: @Harsh I'm sure there is an error with the security rules of firestore. Could you copy and paste it to the question?

Comment: what do you want me to copy paste to the question?

Comment: @Harsh Do you know what security rules are in firestore? I think there's something wrong with it, so I want to see it to fix your issue. Could you go to your firebase console and copy and paste the security rules so that I can fix your issue?

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}