# Unable to fetch data from firebase firestore using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, stream-builder, dart-null-safety

Ive been trying to display images from firestore the code show no error and compiles but not able to display images,i am using web soo only configured for flutter web and rechecked.
I am using cloud_firestore: ^3.1.0, and thought of using the new withConverter functionality.
I want to use it to retrieve and pass my models from and to Firestore, but I am not quite sure why is not displaying.
I think i may be parsing the data incorrectly

**My firestore backend setup imgUrl:**

[image]

```
//Here's my model
class ArtWork {
ArtWork({required this.name, required this.imgUrl});

final String name;
final String imgUrl;

factory ArtWork.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ArtWork(
    name: json['name'],
    imgUrl: json['imgUrl'],
  );

Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
return {
  'name': name,
  'imgUrl': imgUrl,
  };
 }
}
```

Ive used both streamBuilder and FutureBuilder both return same output.

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final artRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('artWorks')
      .withConverter<ArtWork>(
    fromFirestore: (snapshots, _) => ArtWork.fromJson(snapshots.data()!),
    toFirestore: (artwork, _) => artwork.toJson(),
  );

   ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
        child: Card(child: _buildContent(context)),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context) {
    // final database = Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false);
    return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot<ArtWork>>(
      future: widget.artRef.get(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<ArtWork>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(data['name'].toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 60),),
                subtitle: Text(data['imgUrl']),
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        }


        return  Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
```

Output:

```
   Performing hot restart...                                          12.6s
   Restarted application in 12,582ms.
   [.2021-11-09T15:47:17.224Z]  @firebase/firestore:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the exact path to that node by

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('artWorks').doc('nice').withConverter<ArtWork>(...............)
```

If this doesn't fix,try first printing the data using .get()

Comment: i tried to display a single document. I changed the type of stream to documentSnapshot. Another exception was thrown:`Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type '_WithConverterDocumentSnapshot<ArtWork>'`

Comment: have you tried this ?`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('artWorks').doc('nice').withConverter<ArtWork>(...............)`

Comment: yes i did and it says : Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type '_WithConverterDocumentSnapshot<ArtWork>'.         _It can even be some kind of null error i guess_